# Mpandroidchart AxisValueFormatter : I am facing the issue with X-axis labels and marker, X-axis last value is not showing and Marker is misplaced

Tags: android, graph, mpandroidchart

**Mpandroidchart**: I am facing the issue with **X-axis labels and marker**, X-axis last value is not getting display and Marker is misplaced.

```
 chart.getXAxis().setValueFormatter(new ValueFormatter() {
            @Override
            public String getFormattedValue(float value) {
                return TimeUtils.getFormattedDateTime(dateValues.get((int) value), TimeUtils.MMM_DATE_ONLY_FORMAT);
            }
        });


  MyMarkerView mv = new MyMarkerView(this, R.layout.custom_marker_view, getString(R.string.bpm), R.drawable.marker_green);
        mv.setChartView(chart);
        chart.setMarker(mv);
```

Can we add padding from the right? so the marker will take its place

Have a look at the attached image to understand the issue:- https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzqOU.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cs7Fx.png

Answer (score 0):

After wasting a few hours on it, finally got the answer. I'm posting this answer for anyone else who has faced this issue.

Setting

- chart.getXAxis().setSpaceMin(0.5f);

would add space between the X-axis line and the chart itself.

- chart.getXAxis().setSpaceMax(0.5f);

for adding space between the last value and the right X-axis of the chart.

Sets the minimum interval between the y-axis values. This can be used to avoid value duplicating when zooming in to a point where the number of decimals set for the axis no longer allows to distinguish between two axis values.

- xAxis.setGranularity(1f);
- xAxis.setLabelCount(10);

After adding the above lines, the issue resolved! attached screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxmWi.png